# Problems with mutual authentication grpc-java tls client to remote host using okhttpchannelbuilder

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, tls1.2, grpc-java

I'm having errors trying to connect my grpc java client to a remote server.

I am using:

```
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.29.0'
```

So i'm also assuming this might have to do with this being mostly used for android in examples, and my program is a pure java application, no android involved.

This is my code:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
char[] password = "passwordgoeshere".toCharArray();
InputStream clientCertStream = new FileInputStream("file.p12");
InputStream caCertStream = new FileInputStream("file.pem");
keyStore.load(clientCertStream, password);
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(keyStore, password);
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Collection<X509Certificate> certificates = (Collection<X509Certificate>) cf.generateCertificates(caCertStream);
for(X509Certificate certificate: certificates) {
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("caCert", certificate);
}

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(keyStore);
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(),  tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sc.getSocketFactory();

ManagedChannelBuilder builder =
        OkHttpChannelBuilder.forAddress("host", port)
                .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                .connectionSpec(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                .hostnameVerifier((s, sslSession) -> true);
return builder.build();
```

And these are my errors:

```
WARNING: Unable to find Conscrypt
```

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE
```

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells me this is simply an issue of trustChain validation failure i.e. the cert from the remote server is not trusted by your client. Make sure the server's CA's root cert is present in your trust-store (TrustManager).